# MasterCard hosted checkout integration issue

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

I am newbie on payment integration. I need to integrate MasterCard payment gateway services in my php page. I have a button for `PAY` and once clicked,I redirect to the following page. I have following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function errorCallback(error) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
        function cancelCallback() {
              console.log('Payment cancelled');
        }

        Checkout.configure({
            merchant: 'test001000000052',
            order: {
                amount: 100,
                currency: 'AED',
                description: 'Ordered goods',
               id: '123'
            },
            interaction: {
                merchant: {
                    name: 'test',
                    address: {
                        line1: '200 Sample St',
                        line2: '1234 Example Town'            
                    },
                 cancelUrl:'10.0.1.100/?load=parents/online_payment'    
                }
              }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    <input type="button" value="Pay with Lightbox" onclick="Checkout.showLightbox();" />
    <input type="button" value="Pay with Payment Page" onclick="Checkout.showPaymentPage();" /> 
</body>
```

When I click either buttons, I am getting the following error message in console.

```
XHR failed loading: POST "https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/page/version/51/pay". 
{"cause":"INVALID_REQUEST","explanation":"Invalid credentials."}
```

I have used the merchantID correctly,may be I missed something. I have username and password with me and not sure where to add these parameters. Please help me

I have taken the code from https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US

Comment: Where does PHP come into play here?

Comment: @JohnConde I am integrating this payment gateway with PHP file.

Comment: @JohnConde Can you help me what I am missing here

Comment: But the PHP does not affect the code you have here. I am going to remove the PHP tag since it is not applicable.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks.

Comment: `Invalid Credentials` mean that the API Credentials are invalid. Check with your bank as there might be an issue with the configuration of your merchantId.

Answer (score 1):

You Should create a session then open the checkout page or lightbox

Create a session variable

```
$session_request = [
                'apiOperation' => "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION",
                'interaction'  => [
                    'operation' => "PURCHASE",
                    'returnUrl' => "<return url>",
                ],
                'order'        => [
                    'amount'      => <amount>,
                    'currency'    => '<Currency Code like USD>',
                    'description' => 'Full Payment',
                    'id'          => <transaction reference>,
                ],
                'userId'       => <customer ID>,
            ];
```

Call the following function for sending the session data to Mastercard server

```
/**
     * @param        $inputs
     * @param        $link
     * @param        $username
     * @param        $password
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return \Exception|\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException|\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException|mixed|string
     * @throws \GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException
     */
    public static function postJsonRequestWithToken( $inputs, $link, $username, $password, $type = "assoc" ) {
        try {
            $client     = new Client();
            $response   = $client->post( $link, [
                'body' => json_encode( $inputs ),
                'auth' => [
                    $username,
                    $password,
                ],
            ] );
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $body       = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            if ( $type == 'json' ) {
                return $body;
            }
            if ( $type == 'object' ) {
                return json_decode( $body );
            }
            if ( $type == 'assoc' ) {
                return json_decode( $body, true );
            }
            
            return json_decode( $body );
        } catch( ClientException $e ) {
            //return json_decode( $e->getResponse()->getBody(), true );
            return $e;
        } catch( RequestException $e ) {
            //return json_decode( $e->getResponse()->getBody(), true );
            return $e;
        }
        /*} catch( RequestException $e ) {
            echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
            if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
            }
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i have configured my Checkout and when i call ```Checkout.showPaymentPage()``` its working but when i call ```Checkout,showLightbox()``` it doesnt work. Is Checkout.configure different for both of these?

Answer (score 0):

There Two Cases 
1. When you received the merchant ID. They should have shared one documentation link kindly refer that. Mostly the checkout.js file path is wrong.
2. You have to make basic user authentication while making an API call and pass the username and password. You can generate the password from the admin panel

Comment: my issues was not with the password or the path of checkout.js. My issues was in creating a sessionID which we need to create it before doing the payment.I found that and it was resolved

Comment: @Techy check this tutorial it may clarify how it works. https://www.areeba.com/projects/integration/

Comment: In the docs its written test.gateway.mastercard.com/static/checkout/checkout.min.js why do others use checkout.js?

Answer (score 0):

```
static public function initPaymentSession($amount,$orderID,$description,$currency = 'EGP')
{
    // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://banquemisr.gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/60');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "apiOperation=CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION&apiPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&apiUsername=merchant.xxxxxxxxx&merchant=xxxxxxxxx&interaction.operation=PURCHASE&order.id=$orderID&order.amount=$amount&order.currency=EGP");

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        return 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result){
        $res1 = explode('&session.id=', $result);
        $res2 = explode('&', $res1[1]);
        return $res2[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: this for getting session id