# MasterCard payment gateway checkout.js method not triggering complete Callback function

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, mastercard

I am using the master card [checkout.js](https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/57/api.html?locale=en_US) method version 57.
Under the checkout.js there are two types

1. [showLightbox](https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/57/function/showLightbox.html?locale=en_US) -> Show a lightbox to complete payment.
2. [showPaymentPage](https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/57/function/showPaymentPage.html?locale=en_US) -> Redirect to a hosted payment page to complete payment.

when using first method **light box** if the payment process success **completeCallback()** function get trigger. there is no issue with this **showlightbox** method.

But when using the **showPaymentPage** method after the payment process, get redirect to the initiated domain but not triggering the **completeCallback()** function.

how ever if I cancel the payment process get redirect to the initiated domain and triggering the
**cancel Callback** function.

```
<script src="https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js" data-error="errorCallback" 
data-cancel="cancelCallback" 
data-complete="completeCallback"></script>

Checkout.configure({
    merchant: pay_det['merchant'],
    order: {
        amount: function() {                        
            return pay_det['amount'];
        },
        currency: pay_det['currebcy'],
        description: 'Payments',
        id: invID,
        reference : $('#id_invoice').val()
    },
    session : {
        id : pay_det['session_id']
    },
    transaction :{
        reference : 'TR'+pay_det['invID']
    },
    interaction: {                        
        operation : 'PURCHASE',                    
        displayControl: {
            billingAddress : 'HIDE',
            customerEmail  : 'HIDE',
            orderSummary   : 'SHOW',
            shipping       : 'HIDE'
        },
        merchant: {
            name: pay_det['amount'],
            address: {
                line1: pay_det['companyPrintAddress'],
            },                            
        }
    },                                
});

Checkout.showPaymentPage();

function cancelCallback() {
    alert('cancelled');
}

function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
    //var invoiceID = $('#id_invoice').val();
    alert('success');
    console.log(resultIndicator);
}
```

one more thing if I change the **data-complete** attributes value to a url not redirect from the payment gateway to my domain.
form

> data-complete="completeCallback"

to

> data-complete="https://subscription-int.com/567"

When referring the [complete Callback](https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/57/callback/complete.html?locale=en_US) functions reference, documentation says

> The complete callback is only supported in a Return To Merchant integration.

What is **Return To Merchant integration**?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the wrong version of the docs, but I don't see that field in here https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/56/function/configure.html?locale=en_US

Comment: @mattfreake please check the updated post

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `interaction.returnUrl` in the **`Create Checkout Session`** and **NOT IN** `Configure` operation.

Another way of doing this is when referencing the `checkout.js` script, you can define the `complete` callback. Mention  your `returnUrl` as callback value (instead of  function) and the user will be redirected to this URL upon completion of payment.

You'll have the `resultIndicator` appended to your `returnUrl` upon redirection. Compare this with `successIndicator` value that you had received during `Create Checkout Session` response.

[MPGS Hosted Checkout Documentation](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US#)

Comment: I have updated the question, I was on wrong track earlier. please check this update.

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65689876/1304811

Comment: Hi, i have a question. In the apiOperation ```CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION``` if i add 1$ as an amount for card verification and the user enter their card details and presses pay does this mean that the 1$ is deducted from the users account or do i still need to call the ```PAY``` operation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the function to the window object, for example:

```
window.completed = () => {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cancel and complete callback like this.

```
<script src="https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js" data-cancel="https://website.com/payment-rejected.php" data-complete="https://website.com/payment-success.php"> </script>
```

Refer this:

https://nbo.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the code snippet below in my wordpress widget, just make sure you add the returnUrl in the interaction parameter.

```
$id = sanitize_text_field( $req['id'] );
$amount  = sanitize_text_field( $req['amount'] );
$merchantId = sanitize_text_field( $req['merchantId'] );
$password = sanitize_text_field( $req['password'] );
$redirectUrl = sanitize_text_field( $req['redirectUrl'] );

$post_data = '{ 
    "apiOperation": "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION", 
    "interaction": {
        "operation": "PURCHASE",
        "returnUrl": "' . $redirectUrl .'",
    
    },
    "order": {
        "currency": "NGN",
         "id": "' . $id . '",
        "amount": "' . $amount . '"
      } 
  }';

$url = "https://fbn.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/61/merchant/" . $merchantId . "/session";

$auth = 'merchant.'. $merchantId . ':' . $password;
$credentials = base64_encode($auth);
$authorization = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials;

// Prepare new cURL resource
$crl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
 
// Set HTTP Header for POST request 
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $credentials)
);
 
// Submit the POST request
$result = curl_exec($crl);
 
// handle curl error
if ($result === false) {
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    //print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    $result_noti = 0; die();
} else {
    return rest_ensure_response( $result );
}
// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($crl);
```